# Why do I get differnt row reduced echelon form?

Tags: matrix-rank

[image: picture 1]

[image: picture 2]

As far as I know ,one matrix has a unique row reduced echelon form. But why do I get the different echelon form if I change the last row operation of the first picture? What have I done wrong ? What's the exact rule here so that I can get the same result all the time?

Comment: That's unreadable. Please type the question.

Comment: The minimum effort, that is expected when asking a question, is using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write that question.

Comment: I have added two pictures for better understanding.

Comment: As 5xum already mentioned - they are unreadable. Write your operations in mathjax.

Answer (score 0):

RREF is unique.

Review the definition of elementary row operations.

- We can multiply a row by non-zero number.
- We can swap two rows
- We can perform the operation $R_{\color{red}{i}} = R_\color{red}i + cR_\color{blue}j$

Notice that row operations doesn't include the operation $R_{\color{red}{i}} = R_\color{blue}j + cR_\color{red}i$